# Xcode 10 says no App Store connect access for team and application loader says no CFbundle ID

Tags: xcode10

When I archive my Xcode 10 project and I click distribute, It says "No App Store connect access for the team" even though I have created the app and my team info is correct. When I try application loader, the alternate solution to submitting an ap, I say "no CF bundle ID found" I have checked my bundle IDs and they're all the same. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Hello, please introduce yourself to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and correct your question.

Answer (score 16):

Had the same issue - quitting XCODE and restarting it solved it for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: I got the error "no App Store Connect access for team" and this worked for me.

Comment: Also worked for me.  You gotta wonder how these programs work under the hood when things like this happen.

Comment: Close completely is very important because I realized that xcode running in the background when I have looked at the Activity Monitor.